# Create RTF Template, XML BI Publisher Report

Tags: xml, templates, rtf, publisher

I have a data table

```
model    day    number
GS        1          0
LX        1          0
ES        1          1
GS        2          0
LX        2          0
ES        2          0
GS        3          0
LX        3          1
ES        3          0
          31         0
```

Please help me create an RTF Template to show the data:

```
Model     1      2     3     4     5     6     7    31     total  
GS        0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0         0
LX        0      0     1     0     0     0     0     0         1  
ES        1      0     0     0     0     0     0     0         0
Total     1      0     0     0     0     0     0     0         1
```

Comment: hi , i'm try it and result :
Model     1      2     3     4     5     6     7    31     total  
GS        0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0         0
LX        0      0     1     0     0     0     0     0         0  
ES        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0         0
Total     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0         0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want Cross-Tab data.

The Oracle XML Publisher Report Designer's Guide has details on how to do it:

## XML Data

```
<ROWSET>
 <RESULTS>
 <INDUSTRY>Motor Vehicle Dealers</INDUSTRY>
 <YEAR>2005</YEAR>
 <QUARTER>Q1</QUARTER>
 <SALES>1000</SALES>
 </RESULTS>
 <RESULTS>
 <INDUSTRY>Motor Vehicle Dealers</INDUSTRY>
 <YEAR>2005</YEAR>
 <QUARTER>Q2</QUARTER>
 <SALES>2000</SALES>
 </RESULTS>
 <RESULTS>
 <INDUSTRY>Motor Vehicle Dealers</INDUSTRY>
 <YEAR>2004</YEAR>
 <QUARTER>Q1</QUARTER>
 <SALES>3000</SALES>
 </RESULTS>
 <RESULTS>
 <INDUSTRY>Motor Vehicle Dealers</INDUSTRY>
 <YEAR>2004</YEAR>
 <QUARTER>Q2</QUARTER>
 <SALES>3000</SALES>
 </RESULTS>
 <RESULTS>
 <INDUSTRY>Motor Vehicle Dealers</INDUSTRY>
 <YEAR>2003</YEAR>
 ...
 </RRESULTS>
 <RESULTS>
 <INDUSTRY>Home Furnishings</INDUSTRY>
 ...
 </RESULTS>
 <RESULTS>
<INDUSTRY>Electronics</INDUSTRY>
...
</RESULTS>
<RESULTS>
<INDUSTRY>Food and Beverage</INDUSTRY>
...
</RESULTS>
</ROWSET>
```

## Word Template Details

[image: MS Word Details 1]

[image: MS Word Details 2]

[image: MS Word Details 3]

## Results:

[image: Results]